# INSERT INTO ... SELECT

Tags: mysql

Что делают эти операторы в пределах одного выражения? Впервые наткнулся на подобный синтаксис.
Вроде:

```
INSERT INTO tblTemp2 (fldID) SELECT tblTemp1.fldOrder_ID
FROM tblTemp1 WHERE tblTemp1.fldOrder_ID > 100;
```

Вставляет записи по условию, выбирая их?

И подходит ли подобный синтаксис сейчас? Нашел в одном из руководств, но вычитал, что для MySQL не подходит. Правда ли это?

```
SELECT val1+val2 INTO 't' FROM `my` LIMIT 0,1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала выполняется запрос  `SELECT ... WHERE ...`, и его результат `tblTemp1.fldOrder_ID` добавляется в таблицу `tblTemp2` в поле `fldID`

Второй вариант, который вы указали не будет работать, так как нарушена структура SQL-синтаксиса

Comment: Во второй фразе лучше было бы сказать "MySQL не поддерживает синтаксис select into" или как то так. Потому что в других базах данных такой синтаксис рабочий http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp